# Conceptually understanding positional access operations on containers

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, containers, terminology

What the definition of an *positional access operation*<sup>†</sup> on a container could look like, seems to be quite straightforward to me when it comes to `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::list` and `std::forward_list`. That is to say, **accessing the k<sup>th</sup> element** in a collection consists of  *obtaining the element stored **at position k<sup>th</sup>** in the collection*<sup>X</sup>.

For example, the expression `vec[k-1]` accesses the `k`<sup>th</sup> in an `std::vector`, whereas `*std::next(lst.begin(), k-1)` corresponds to its `std::list` counterpart.

However, when it comes to *associative containers* like `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`, it is not so clear to me whether talking about *positional access operations* actually makes sense, since I don't find a straightforward way to determine the location of an arbitrary position k<sup>th</sup> in such containers.

We can still, however, proceed as with the `std::list` example shown above, i.e., taking an iterator to the "first" element of the associative container (e.g., the iterator returned by the member function `begin()`) and then move the iterator forward *k-1* times (e.g., by means of `std::next()`).

I've observed that the containers `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::list` and `std::forward_list` are all implemented using *linear* data structures, whereas `std::set`, which is usually implemented as a binary tree, is not. So, perhaps this issue has to do with the *linearity* of the underlying data structures the containers implement.

Is there any way to clearly define the semantics of a positional access operation for an associative container? Or are such access operations *not applicable* to them?

---

<sup>†</sup> Do not  mix up *search* and *access* operations. In a search operation, you are looking for an element with a given key in the collection.

---

<sup>X</sup> This is regardless of the running time it takes to do so (e.g., linear for a `std::list` instead of constant time for a `std::vector`) or whether there is no dedicated member function (e.g., the lack of subscript operator in `std::list`) for achieving that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big difference between the categories of containers you mentioned are that the first are *sequence* containers, where it's the user of the container that determines explicitly where to put elements, while the latter are *associative* containers, where the resulting order is implicitly determined from some properties of the elements to make it possible to access them by key (`std::map`/`std::unordered_map`)/value (`std::set`/`std::unordered_set`) efficiently.

This doesn't mean that accessing by "position" in such containers is useless - as an `std::set` keeps its elements sorted, the k<sup>th</sup> item in a `std::set` is the k<sup>th</sup> smallest element in the set (although indeed I cannot think of any purpose for accessing an `std::unordered_set` by position - hashes generally don't produce any particularly useful ordering<sup>1</sup>).

Besides this conceptual distinction, I don't see any big operative difference between accessing the k<sup>th</sup> element of a `std::list` and doing the same over a `std::set` - in both cases the operation is not "natively" supported by the container (as in, the container doesn't support O(1) random access), and you have to walk it one element at time. Even under the hood, walking a binary tree such as those generally employed by `std::set` or `std::map` is not that different from following the links in a linked list (such as in `std::list`).

---

1. If `std::hash` was a cryptographical hash, which "whites" out the original data, it may make some feeble sense as "accessing some element of a random permutation", but `std::hash` is just required to be well distributed over the type range, so e.g. integers [are often hashed as themselves](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-QzOCi) - not a particularly interesting permutation.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed for a list it is possible to define the k<sup>th</sup> element the one pointed to by the pointer which is next to the pointer pointing to the k<sup>th-1</sup> element.

You could also notice that in number theory a number is also defined as a sequence:
1 is the number next to 0, 2 is the number next to 1, etc...

So one can create an isomorphism of the structure formed by the pointers to the element of a container and their next operation, to the structure of natural numbers with the +1 operation:

```
p0:=begin()                               O
  |next                                   |increment
p1:=next(begin())   --isomorphic to-->    1:=increment(0)
  |next                                   |increment
p2:=next(next(begin()))                   2:=increment(increment(0))
  .                                       .
  .                                       .
```

This isomorphism can be used for any container as long as they provide a begin pointer. So, for the sake of the concept of position, any STL containers are equivalent.

Comment: very interesting answer. So, as long as the containers provide a forward iterator to the initial element, then an isomorphism can be created.